# Dynamically inserting script in Google Apps Script web app?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
 var script = document.createElement("script");
 script.type = "text/javascript";
 script.defer = true;
 script.text = "alert(1)";
 document.getElementById("myContent").appendChild(script);
```

Above code works well separately, but does not work in App Script web app. Does caja plays some role here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes caja plays a role. You cannot inject or self modify the js.

Comment: Include as external js like you would do with jquery